# Manifold with $\pi_1(M)=F_n$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

We may construct a 3-manifold $M_n$ with $\pi_1(M_n)\cong F_n$ (i.e. the free group on $n$ generators) as follows: consider the complement of $n$ pairs of open 3-balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For each pair, identify the corresponding boundary spheres. It is easy to see that this manifold has the free group on $n$ generators as a fundamental group. Lets identify with each pair of spheres a generating loop $x_i$. Clearly, $\pi_1(M_n)\cong <x_1,...,x_n>$. My question is as follows: if possible, how can we modify $M_n$ such that $x_ix_j=x_jx_i$ for some $i$ and $j$. If this is not possible what is the obstruction?

Comment: You want that relation for *one* pair of $i$ and $j$, or for all pairs?

Comment: when you say 'manifold' you mean compact w/o boundary, I guess?

Comment: Specifically for some pair $x_i$ and $x_j$. And Grigory M - since $M_n$ is not closed as defined, I'd expect that the modification of $M_n$ to allow $x_i$ and $x_j$ to commute would not change this.

Comment: Edit: I should note that we can make this manifold compact by considering the same construction in $S^3$ in place of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: The answer depends on what do you mean by a manifold (closed or not). If you insist on a closed manifold, the answer is no, if not, the answer is yes.

Comment: studiosus - if we we do not require the manifold to be closed then how would we get the elements to commute? Also, if you don't mind, why does this fail in the closed case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your construction of the 3-manifold $M_n$ can be reworded by saying that it is a connected sum of the form
$$(*) \qquad M_n \, = \, \mathbb{R}^3 \, \# \, \underbrace{(S^2 \times S^1) \, \# \, \cdots \, \# \, (S^2 \times S^1)}_{n \,\,\text{times}}
$$

The group you want to obtain instead is simply the free product $F_{n-2} * \mathbb{Z}^2$. This is obtained by altering your construction, replacing two of the $S^2 \times S^1$ connected summands with a single $T^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ connected summand:
$$(**) \qquad \mathbb{R}^3 \, \# \, \underbrace{(S^2 \times S^1) \, \# \, \cdots \, \# \, (S^2 \times S^1)}_{n-2 \,\,\text{times}} \, \# \, (T^2 \times \mathbb{R})
$$

As noted in the comments, you can drop the $\mathbb{R}^3$ connected summand of $(*)$ without changing the fundamental group and you get a compact manifold. But although you can also drop the $\mathbb{R}^3$ connected summand of $(**)$ without changing the fundamental group, that will not result in a compact manifold because the $T^2 \times \mathbb{R}$ connected summand remains noncompact.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness: If $M^3$ is a *closed* connected 3-dimensional manifold (closed means compact and without boundary), its fundamental group cannot be isomorphic to the free product $F_n \star Z^2$ for any $n$. Otherwise, by Kneser's theorem, this free product decomposition would correspond to a connected sum decomposition of $M$ into pieces with fundamental groups isomorphic to $Z$ and to $Z^2$. However, a closed 3-manifold cannot have the fundamental group $Z^2$.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. It seems your last statement depends on the fact that the manifold must be prime since its fundamental group is abelian. This would imply that $M$ is $K(\pi, 1)$. This means that $M$ must have the homotopy type of $(S^1)^n$ hence $n=3$ is the only valid solution. Correct?

Comment: @JosephZambrano: Yes, this is correct.